# Writing dictionary values in separate XML tags vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, dictionary, tags

If I had multiple entries under my value in my dictionary, is there anyway I can put each value in separate tags to create an xml document?

Is there anyway to split the 3 values into their own tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over the service class, it would be easier to get what you want by using ReadOnly Properties to access the individual fields.  Then you could use those fields with your stringBuilder to use the individual fields instead of the .ToString.

Like:

```
Class Services

Private _displayName As String
Private _serviceName As String
Private _serviceStatus As String

Public ReadOnly Property ServiceStatus As String
    Get
        Return _serviceStatus
    End Get
End Property
Public ReadOnly Property ServiceName As String
    Get
        Return _serviceName
    End Get
End Property
Public ReadOnly Property DisplayName As String
    Get
        Return _displayName
    End Get
End Property


'etc
```

Change the builder in the loop to something more like:

```
sbService.AppendFormat("<Name>""{0}""<DisplayName>""{1}""</DisplayName><ServiceName>{2}</ServiceName><Status>{3}</Status></Name>",
item.Key, item.Value._displayName, item.Value.ServiceName, item.Value.ServiceStatus).AppendLine()
```

Like the other guy said I would probably also work new lines in to make the output more readable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add anew line character to separate your tags. 
Change your code to:

```
sbService.AppendFormat("<Name>" & vbCrLf & "{0}" & vbCrLf & "<Details>" & vbCrLf & "{1}" & vbCrLf & "</Details>" & vbCrLf & "</Name>", item.Key, item.Value.ToString()).AppendLine()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although it makes the code easier to read, i was trying to find out if i could could put each of the 3 child values from the dictionary into 3 separate tags